# PyCharm is not searching the entire project

Tags: search, pycharm

When I use the find tool in PyCharm, it only searches the page that is currently in focus. If the string is found in the current file, it shows the results on that page, and then the "Find all" button is enabled. When I click it, it shows a directory tree of the entire project, yielding only the results that were found in the original file. "Find all" does not find all references in the project.

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit >> Find >> Find in Path (This will search the entire project.)

Highlighting an expression and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> finds all usage also.

**Update:** In the version I am currently using, PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3, the shortcut is to highlight the expression and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

1) Edit >> Find >> Find in Path
Make sure to click on "Scope" so that it searches in all the project.